# True Polymorph interaction with Find Steed

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

[Find Steed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-steed#:%7E:text=You%20summon%20a%20spirit%20that,an%20elk%2C%20or%20a%20mastiff.) (p240 PHB) States:

> When the steed drops to 0 hit points, it disappears, leaving behind no physical form. You can also dismiss your steed at any time as an action, causing it to disappear. In either case, **casting this spell again summons the same steed, restored to its hit point maximum.**

If I were to cast [True Polymorh](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph#:%7E:text=The%20creature%20is%20limited%20in,is%20capable%20of%20such%20actions.) (p283 PHB) on the steed and wait the full duration to make it permanent, would the steed return when summoned as the original steed or as the new creature it was polymorphed into?

Comment: Keep in mind that whatever the answer is, even if it did work because of the CR restriction of True Polymorph it's not going to make a huge difference... you might have a Black Bear instead of a Warhorse or a Boar instead of an Elk, but that's about it.

Comment: Yeah its more for aesthetics, I could use find greater steed for more HP if I wanted.. but honestly I just want to have a humanoid "shadow" to fight along side me, that is more substantial than a moon blade or an ecco knight.

Comment: Related (very not a duplicate): "[How do Polymorph and Find \[Greater\] Steed interact?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/170169)"

Comment: Related, or possible duplicate(s): https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156451/38834 and https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136172/38834 - Except with familiars

Comment: Those are not duplicates because familiar works differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steed would return in its old form.

The first two lines of Find Steed read as following:

> You summon a spirit that assumes the form of an unusually intelligent, strong, and loyal steed, creating a long-lasting bond with it. Appearing in an unoccupied space within range, the steed takes on a form that you choose;

When the spell refers to "the steed", it means the spirit, not the form that it takes when you summon it. When the spell says "you summon the same steed" it's saying that the spirit recognizes you and remembers how you treated it.

The form of the steed can change every time you summon it and you have to choose the form from the list given by the spell, so even if it's been polymorphed you can't choose that form because it's not part of the spell.

Comment: Hi Matteo, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here, and visit the [help] for more guidance. This is a good first answer!

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Have a look at our [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) page and stay awhile. This is a great first answer.